# License to use with Apple App Store Submission

Tags: ios, app-store

This is my first iPhone application that I am creating for a client and he asked me to submit the app using my own Apple Development License (Individual & Not Company License) so my question which might be very basic; can I submit the App using my own development license but it appears at the end on the App Store under the client's company name (i.e. is their a field or something while submitting the app that we use to tell the owner of the app)?

P.S. I tried searching for this specific questions but most of the websites/threads are talking about submission guidelines and probably my question is a very basic question before going into the guidelines

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you submit as you, it appears under your name in the App Store. You can, however, transfer an app to another party.

FAQ on [Transferring App Ownership](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/26.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.5.10.1).

From the FAQ:

> **What are the requirements for transferring an app?
>   To transfer an app, make sure that:**
>
> - The transferor and the recipient have active developer accounts and accepted the most current version of all master agreements that are currently in effect
> - The app has at least one approved version
> - The app is in the Ready for Sale, Invalid Binary, Rejected, Developer Rejected, or Developer Removed from Sale state
> - Any associated In-App Purchases are in the Ready to Submit, Ready for Sale, Rejected, Developer Removed from Sale, or Approved state
> - You know the Apple ID of the recipient’s Team Agent and their Team ID

Comment: It seems that my client will need to register his own "Company License" so that the app appears under his company's name, do you know if this is straight forward or not, my individual development license was straight forward but for the company I bit Apple has complicated things

Comment: The hardest part is they'll need a Dun and Bradstreet (["D-U-N-S"](http://www.dnb.com/get-a-duns-number.html)) number. Start this now because it could take a few days. If they're a real business (LLC, whatever), they should already have everything else they need.

Comment: Sorry, I can't resist to LOL at the "few days"... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is customary for developers to first submit apps (or major revisions) to the store under their own identity ... or, in larger companies, to a separate "development" identity ... and then to transfer the apps when they are really ready to be sold to the public.  (Companies often do not *want* to draw attention to these apps until that time.)

If the company does not yet have their own Apple identity, you should instruct them to start getting the necessary paperwork in place *now,* so that ownership of the app can be transferred without delay.

Don't let the company initially offer the product for sale under your identity. *(See above.)* You've got a developer identity basically [just ...] so that *beta-testers* can actually download from the store.